# Processing PHP On same Domain

Tags: php

I have a file

```
example.com/process.php
```

Whcih give a captcha image on webpage
Now How to make that PHP Script Domain protected Means Other then domain "Example.com" Cannot Get the processing data of That PHP File

How to make It Domain protected
Means Only

```
example.com
```

process that captcha.

Is this possible.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question please? It's hard to understand what problem you have.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist This could be very helpful

Comment: Dainis I Have updated The question

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand more than before.

Comment: If process.php is outside of your publicly accessible web folder, then nobody else can access it. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your process.php you can do something like this....

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='example.com'))
{
//perform your captcha code.. or whatever..
}
else
{
echo "Sorry other domains/hosts not allowed to access this page";
}
```

Comment: But Whenever this process.php accessed from another webserver or website its always process. :(